# BottomNavigationView - How to disable selected icon highlight

Tags: android, android-bottomnavigationview

I have a bottomnavigation view that sets an icon depending on the state if it's checked or not.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon_tree"
        android:title="Tree"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottomnav_icon_home">
    </item>

</menu>
```

bottomnav_icon_home:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_home_black" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_home_green" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

[image]

How ever bottomnavigation is automatically highlighting the icon when android:state_checked is true.

[image]

How do I completely disable bottomnavigation's icon selection highlight?

I've tried setting `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"` to `@null` however that doesn't work

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:itemIconSize="28dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

bottom_navigation_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/forestGreen" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorBlack" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Why not using the same color for both state?

Comment: What do you mean? I have two icon states that I want. One with black highlight and white inside, and one with black highlight with green inside. Does using same color for both state have that outcome?

Comment: Setting them both to black removes the green https://i.imgur.com/8ClmMSD.png

Comment: try creating a new style, see if the highlight still works

Comment: What do you mean by How do I completely disable bottomnavigation's icon selection highlight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understood you right, android by default sets a tint on your bottom navigation  icons on selection and you would like it to be removed right.

I know how to do that in your java class not xml though.

You'll need to set `setItemIconTintList` method of your `BottomNavigationView` to `null`. So in wherever you set the layout write code as :

```
BottomNavigationView btmNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
btmNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Would prefer an XML way, but I've searched through the docs and there doesn't seem like there is one? Maybe I missed it?

Comment: Had a similar requirement, tried to find a way in xml myself but this was the only way i could disable the feature. Hope someone finds another way in xml...

Comment: Thanks for your help appreciate it, I'll give you the bounty =)

Comment: Can u answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77125836/3319132

Answer (score 1):

try to add this line in the dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">@dimen/design_bottom_navigation_text_size</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom style.

There are two steps.

1- Create custom `bottom_navigation_bar_icon_color.xml` in drawable folder. This is the selector showed the icon highlighted or default. So you can highlight all icons or show them as default. Choose one of the following when creating your `bottom_navigation_bar_icon_color.xml`

- Icons highlighted:    `<item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>`
- Icons default:     `<item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary"/>`

bottom_navigation_bar_icon_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

2- Add following custom style to themes.xml or styles.xml. `bottom_navigation_bar_icon_color` used in itemIconTint and itemTextColor

```
<style name="BottomNavigationThemeCustom">
    <item name="enforceTextAppearance">true</item>
    <item name="enforceMaterialTheme">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@drawable/bottom_navigation_bar_icon_color</item>
    <item name="itemRippleColor">@color/mtrl_navigation_bar_colored_ripple_color</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">?attr/textAppearanceCaption</item>
    <item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">?attr/textAppearanceCaption</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@drawable/bottom_navigation_bar_icon_color</item>
</style>
```

3- Use your new style for bottomNavigationBar

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            style="@style/BottomNavigationThemeCustom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

4- If you want to hide the bottomNavigationBar on Scroll add following attribute to bottomNavigationBar

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
```

Answer (score 0):

You consider create your own implementation of bottomNavigation?
When I implement the Google BottomNavigationView, I got a lot of issues, so I create a new one like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="@color/grayBottomNavigationDelimiter"/>

    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorNavigationBar"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:text="@string/navigation_home_text"
            style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"/>
...
```

So, can see this is easier than imagine, did you?

Answer (score 0):

To add it through XML: For the attribute **IconItemTint** and **ItemTextColor**, simply use the same color that you've used for icons by default. In that case, the highlight color and default color will be the same. Will give you the required ripple effect on selecting but highlight wont be visible.

For my black color icon, I've used this:

```
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:itemTextColor="#000000"
```

My entire bottom nav looks like this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:itemTextColor="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_more_options_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.None"`
into the bottom navigation tag so that selection highlight disappears.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/ShapeAppearance.Material3.Corner.None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to remove that blue highlight by using

```
app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/white"
```

in my BottomNavigationView

this is my complete code

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:itemIconSize="100dp"
    app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/white"
    android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```